# How to load translated message from po file in cakephp model

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a localization in cakephp 2.10.12. I have successfully load the translated word in view of cakephp by using __('key'). As shown below :

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label ><?php echo __('PutMoneyAmount') ;?></label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The problem rightnow is load/use `__('key')` in the model. Because there is a message validation there that needs to be translated also. Here's the code in my model :

```
public $validate = array(
    'currency_amount' => array(
        'formatCheck' => array (
            'rule' => 'money',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => __('CurrencyError')
        )
    ),
    'date_input' => array(
        'rule' => 'date',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => __('DateError')
    )
);
```

When I put those `__('CurrencyError')` and `__('DateError')`, my screen shows an error `Error: Constant expression contains invalid operations` 
So How do I load those translated key in the cakephp model ?
Thank you

NOTE :
Here's is my translation file in English, Japan, and Indonesia
English :

```
msgid "CurrencyError"
msgstr "Please input a valid monetary amount."

msgid "DateError"
msgstr "Please input a valid date."
```

Japan :

```
msgid "CurrencyError"
msgstr "有効な金額を入力してください。"

msgid "DateError"
msgstr "有効な日付を入力してください。"
```

Indonesia :

```
msgid "CurrencyError"
msgstr "Silahkan masukkan jumlah uang yang valid"

msgid "DateError"
msgstr "Silahkan masukkan tanggal yang valid"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public $validate = array(
    'currency_amount' => array(
        'formatCheck' => array (
            'rule' => 'money',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => __('CurrencyError')
        )
    ),
    'date_input' => array(
        'rule' => 'date',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => __('DateError')
    )
);
```

to this

```
public $validate = array(
    'currency_amount' => array(
        'formatCheck' => array (
            'rule' => 'money',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'CurrencyError'
        )
    ),
    'date_input' => array(
        'rule' => 'date',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'DateError'
    )
);
```

Unlike in the View .ctp files. You dont need to put it under '__(key)' in the model. As long as you put your translation correctly in the locale file it would automatically translate.

**Edit** : I think this could help you resolve your problem temporarily. Here, we use the validate from the model and any validation error would be translated manually. Using the __d('key'). But if anyone could suggest anything better then please do follow that since this is a double foreach loop. I will also keep an eye on this post to see if there is a better answer.

```
if (!$this->Model->validates($data)) {
  foreach ($this->Model->validationErrors as $field => $errors) {
  // get the value of error message and put it to errContainer
   foreach ($errors as $error) {
     $errContainer[$rowCnt][] = __d('default', $error);
   }
  }
}
```

Here is a link in regards to your problem stated in the Cakephp2 documentation. https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#translating-model-validation-errors

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
if I just put 'CurrencyError', it only loads english translation. Other language is not

Comment: Have you put the translation in the Locale -> (translation language) -> LC_Message -> default.po

For example
Locale -> jpn -> LC_Message -> default.po 
And inside that default.po i have my translation string that is 

msgid "Please enter the Password within 4 digits."
msgstr "パスワードは4桁で入力してください"

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will take a look. Rightnow I only translate it in the view side. So each message error is identified by array key index that will be used to take translation from po file in view